# BitTorrent DHT protocol

Tags: bittorrent, dht

BitTorrent DHT protocol at the end addresses *list of peers* for the querying node, but after receiving peer list which protocol is followed between peers for actual trading of pieces?

Answer (score 1):

The [core bittorrent protocol (BEP 3)](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html)

By default it uses TCP as underlying transport but can optionally use [µTP (BEP 29)](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0029.html).

There are a bunch of other commonly deployed [BEPs](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0000.html) (6, 9, 10, 11) that extend it further.